# adding extra parameter to ruby on rails path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm really new to ruby and coming from a php background.

But I want to create a link to a path and add an extra parameter on the end of the path.

Here's what I have:

```
<%= link_to 'View Answers', quiz_path(@quiz "answers=true") %>
```

with out the `answers=true` the link resolves to `http://localhost:3000/quizzes/3`, which is as expected and works fine. But when I add the `answers=true` i get `http://localhost:3000/quizzes/3.answers=true`.

This is so close. But of course I need the `.` to be a `?`.

Obviously I not doing this quite right, but if can help me with a simple a solution about how to add an extra parameter in the link url I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= link_to 'View Answers', quiz_path(quiz: @quiz, answers: true) %>`

You could try the same thing just removing the `quiz:` part (so it's `(@quiz, answers:true)`), but I think the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= link_to 'View Answers', quiz_path(@quiz), :answers => "true"  %>
```

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Example:

```
link_to "Ruby on Rails search", :controller => "searches", :query => "ruby on rails"

    # => <a href="/searches?query=ruby+on+rails">Ruby on Rails search</a>
```